# How does one render an Open Gl Rendered animation to a video file?

Tags: rendering

I'm just trying to render a small animation to video as the open gl render, but I can't find a way to save the animation to my desktop. When I click open gl render animation, it just plays the video inside blender and wont't let me save it to my desktop. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If it's playing he animation, chances are it's recording it somewhere as well. - Have you set the output to where it's supposed to go?  At right under the render properties, go down to the "Output" tab to see the path and video file type.